# error htmlTreeParse in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to get the body text from this webpage www.kinyo.es
but it returns this problem:

```
Error in which(value == defs) : 
  argument "code" is missing, with no default
In addition: Warning messages:
1: XML content does not seem to be XML: 'Error displaying the error page: Application Instantiation Error: Could not connect to MySQL.' 
2: XML content does not seem to be XML: ''
```

My code is the following loop:

```
for(i in 1:n)
{

#get the URL
u <- webpage[i]

doc <- getURL(u)

#get the text from the body
html <- htmlTreeParse(doc, useInternal = TRUE)
txt <- xpathApply(html, "//body//text()[not(ancestor::script)][not(ancestor::style)][not(ancestor::noscript)]", xmlValue)
txt<-toString(txt)
txt

#clean
txt<-(str_replace_all(txt, "[\r\n\t,]" , ""))
txt<-tolower(txt)
txt
search <- c("wi-fi","router","switch","adsl","wireless")
search
stri_count_fixed(txt, search)

conta[i]<-sum(stri_count_fixed(txt, search))
#txt
}
```

Comment: At what line the error occurs? Is the entire loop necessary for reproducing this problem? Can you share the website you're trying to scrape?

Comment: I used the loop because I've a vector of web page to scrape, this is the web page that gives me the problem www.kinyo.es

Comment: I can scrape that page with your code without any error, even if it returns 0. You should mention the packages you are using: `RCurl`, `stringr` AND `stringi`. You may be better off using `rvest` or `xml2`

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit of a stretch, as I read your other questions and I can only suppose this is what you are after:

```r
library(rvest)
library(stringr)

count_keywords <- function(url, keywords){
    read_html(url) %>% 
        html_nodes(xpath = '//body//text()[not(ancestor::script)][not(ancestor::style)][not(ancestor::noscript)]') %>% 
        html_text() %>% 
        toString() %>% 
        str_count(keywords) %>% 
        sum
}

urls <- c('http://www.dlink.com/it/it', 'http://www.kinyo.es')
search <- c("Wi-Fi","Router","Switch","ADSL")

res <- sapply(urls, count_keywords, search)

res
#> http://www.dlink.com/it/it        http://www.kinyo.es 
#>                         11                          0
```